# How to add image in Visualforce Email Template?

Tags: visualforce, email-template, html, images

I'm trying to add a logo in a Visualforce email template. I uploaded the image as a static resource and am referencing the URL for it in the img tag as below:

```
<img alt="Logo" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Logo)}" style="display: block;" />
```

I'm able to see the logo perfectly fine in the template preview but it's not loading in the actual email. I also have images enabled and can download them so I don't think it's an issue with the email carrier. The cache control for the static resource is also set to Public. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please refer below link, it helped me to resolve the issue https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_template_images.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the apex:image tag?

```
<apex:image value="{!$Resource.Logo}" style="display:block;">
```

Comment: The picture is suddenly loading now even though I haven't changed anything. I think there may have been an issue on Salesforce's end. The image is now loading using both <img/> and <apex: image/>

Comment: May have been a caching problem, something on the SF end, or something completely different altogether. Glad it works now though!